# What is the most effective way to flatten a nested json response structure with PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Given a json array from an API response like the below:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "collection_name": "gym_equipment",
        "total_price": 5400,
        "lineitems": [
            {
                "item_no": 1,
                "item_name": "dumbell",
                "quantity": 5,
                "price": 200,
                "splitaccountings": [
                    {
                        "internalorder": "yes",
                        "percentage": 50,
                        "test": "no"
                    },
                    {
                        "internalorder": "no",
                        "percentage": 50,
                        "test": "yes"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "item_no": 2,
                "item_name": "kettlebell",
                "quantity": 5,
                "price": 300,
                "splitaccountings": [
                    {
                        "internalorder": "yes",
                        "percentage": 50,
                        "test": "no"
                    },
                    {
                        "internalorder": "no",
                        "percentage": 50,
                        "test": "yes"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "item_no": 2,
                "item_name": "weight-set",
                "quantity": 15,
                "price": 420,
                "splitaccountings": [
                    {
                        "internalorder": "yes",
                        "percentage": 50,
                        "test": "no"
                    },
                    {
                        "internalorder": "no",
                        "percentage": 50,
                        "test": "yes"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "collection_name": "holiday_equipment",
        "total_price": 5400,
        "lineitems": [
            {
                "item_no": 1,
                "item_name": "suncream",
                "quantity": 5,
                "price": 200,
                "splitaccountings": [
                    {
                        "internalorder": "yes",
                        "percentage": 50,
                        "test": "no"
                    },
                    {
                        "internalorder": "no",
                        "percentage": 50,
                        "test": "yes"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "item_no": 2,
                "item_name": "beer",
                "quantity": 15,
                "price": 420,
                "splitaccountings": [
                    {
                        "internalorder": "yes",
                        "percentage": 100,
                        "test": "no"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "collection_name": "hiking_equipment",
        "total_price": 5400,
        "lineitems": [
            {
                "item_no": 1,
                "item_name": "100",
                "quantity": 5,
                "price": 200,
                "splitaccountings": [
                    {
                        "internalorder": "yes",
                        "percentage": 50,
                        "test": "no"
                    },
                    {
                        "internalorder": "no",
                        "percentage": 50,
                        "test": "yes"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

As you can see there are nested objects within the json array. I want to return a single dataframe which contains all the fields from the json response. This is the output I need:

```
+--------+-----------------+-----------+------------------+--------------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------+
|order_id|collection_name  |total_price|**lineitem_item_no|**lineitem_item_name|**lineitem_quantity|**lineitem_price|**splitaccounting_internalorder|**splitaccounting_percentage|**splitaccounting_test|
+--------+-----------------+-----------+------------------+--------------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------+
|1       |gym_equipment    |5400       |1                 |dumbell             |5                  |200             |yes                            |50                          |no                    |
|1       |gym_equipment    |5400       |1                 |dumbell             |5                  |200             |no                             |50                          |yes                   |
|1       |gym_equipment    |5400       |2                 |kettlebell          |5                  |300             |yes                            |50                          |no                    |
|1       |gym_equipment    |5400       |2                 |kettlebell          |5                  |300             |no                             |50                          |yes                   |
|1       |gym_equipment    |5400       |2                 |weight-set          |15                 |420             |yes                            |50                          |no                    |
|1       |gym_equipment    |5400       |2                 |weight-set          |15                 |420             |no                             |50                          |yes                   |
|2       |holiday_equipment|5400       |1                 |suncream            |5                  |200             |yes                            |50                          |no                    |
|2       |holiday_equipment|5400       |1                 |suncream            |5                  |200             |no                             |50                          |yes                   |
|2       |holiday_equipment|5400       |2                 |beer                |15                 |420             |yes                            |100                         |no                    |
|3       |hiking_equipment |5400       |1                 |100                 |5                  |200             |yes                            |50                          |no                    |
|3       |hiking_equipment |5400       |1                 |100                 |5                  |200             |no                             |50                          |yes                   |
+--------+-----------------+-----------+------------------+--------------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------+
```

This is my current way of achieveing this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, col

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("nested_json_processing").getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format("json").load("/content/test.json")
df.show(truncate=False)

# Explode 'lineitems'
lineitems_exploded = df.select(
    col("id").alias("order_id"), 
    col("collection_name"), 
    col("total_price"),
    explode(col("lineitems")).alias("lineitem")
)

lineitems_exploded.show()
# Further explode 'splitaccountings' from the lineitems
splitaccountings_exploded = lineitems_exploded.select(
    col("order_id"),
    col("collection_name"),
    col("total_price"),
    col("lineitem.item_no").alias("**lineitem_item_no"),
    col("lineitem.item_name").alias("**lineitem_item_name"),
    col("lineitem.quantity").alias("**lineitem_quantity"),
    col("lineitem.price").alias("**lineitem_price"),
    explode(col("lineitem.splitaccountings")).alias("splitaccounting")
)
splitaccountings_exploded.show()

# Flatten all fields
flattened_df = splitaccountings_exploded.select(
    col("order_id"),
    col("collection_name"),
    col("total_price"),
    col("**lineitem_item_no"),
    col("**lineitem_item_name"),
    col("**lineitem_quantity"),
    col("**lineitem_price"),
    col("splitaccounting.internalorder").alias("**splitaccounting_internalorder"),
    col("splitaccounting.percentage").alias("**splitaccounting_percentage"),
    col("splitaccounting.test").alias("**splitaccounting_test")
)

# Show the flattened DataFrame
flattened_df.show(truncate=False)

# Stop the Spark session if no longer needed
spark.stop()
```

I am pretty new to Spark, so I am curious if there are better ways to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Let us use `inline` twice to explode the array of structs into rows and columns

```
result = (
    df
    .select('*', F.inline('lineitems'))
    .select('*', F.inline('splitaccountings'))
    .drop('lineitems', 'splitaccountings')
)
```

---

```
+-----------------+---+-----------+----------+-------+-----+--------+-------------+----------+----+
|  collection_name| id|total_price| item_name|item_no|price|quantity|internalorder|percentage|test|
+-----------------+---+-----------+----------+-------+-----+--------+-------------+----------+----+
|    gym_equipment|  1|       5400|   dumbell|      1|  200|       5|          yes|        50|  no|
|    gym_equipment|  1|       5400|   dumbell|      1|  200|       5|           no|        50| yes|
|    gym_equipment|  1|       5400|kettlebell|      2|  300|       5|          yes|        50|  no|
|    gym_equipment|  1|       5400|kettlebell|      2|  300|       5|           no|        50| yes|
|    gym_equipment|  1|       5400|weight-set|      2|  420|      15|          yes|        50|  no|
|    gym_equipment|  1|       5400|weight-set|      2|  420|      15|           no|        50| yes|
|holiday_equipment|  2|       5400|  suncream|      1|  200|       5|          yes|        50|  no|
|holiday_equipment|  2|       5400|  suncream|      1|  200|       5|           no|        50| yes|
|holiday_equipment|  2|       5400|      beer|      2|  420|      15|          yes|       100|  no|
| hiking_equipment|  3|       5400|       100|      1|  200|       5|          yes|        50|  no|
| hiking_equipment|  3|       5400|       100|      1|  200|       5|           no|        50| yes|
+-----------------+---+-----------+----------+-------+-----+--------+-------------+----------+----+
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems more elegant. My only problem is that as you can see in my example the columns coming from the arrays have a prefix in their column names like "**lineitem_" and "**splitaccounting_". I need this because in some real life cases fields in the nested arrays can have the same name as fields in the root indent. Could you show an example how to add this prefix?

Comment: HI @Looz. Lemme provide you the solution for that scenario in sometime!